# XML extracting attributes using XMLDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

i am trying to parse an xml element using `XMLDocument` (`DItem` >> `Title`)
below is my code but somehow i am not getting hold of it.... any help?

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNamespaceManager xmlns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
            xmlns.AddNamespace("DItems", "http://namespace.xsd");
            xmldoc.Load(url); 

        var title = xmldoc.SelectNodes("content", xmlns);
        foreach (XmlNode node in title)
        {
            string title = node.Attributes["Title"].Value;
            //this.ddlTitle.Items.Add(new ListItem(title));
        }
```

here is my XML:

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">title</title>
  <entry>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <Items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.namespace.xsd">
        <CatalogSource Acronym="ABC" OrganizationName="organization name" />
        <Item Id="28466" CatalogUrl="url">
          <DItem xmlns:content="http://namespace.xsd" TargetUrl="http://index.html" Title="my title1">
            <content:Source Acronym="ABC" OrganizationName="ABC" />
          </DItem>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <Items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.namespace.xsd">
        <CatalogSource Acronym="ABC" OrganizationName="organization name" />
        <Item Id="28466" CatalogUrl="url">
          <DItem xmlns:content="http://namespace.xsd" TargetUrl="http://index.html" Title="my title2">
            <content:Source Acronym="ABC" OrganizationName="ABC" />
          </DItem>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <Items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.namespace.xsd">
        <CatalogSource Acronym="ABC" OrganizationName="organization name" />
        <Item Id="28466" CatalogUrl="url">
          <DItem xmlns:content="http://namespace.xsd" TargetUrl="http://index.html" Title="my title3">
            <content:Source Acronym="ABC" OrganizationName="ABC" />
          </DItem>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </content>
  </entry> 
</root>
```

Comment: Try doing     xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("title"); What you are doing is searching inside the "content\" xml tree, but title is outside of that tree.

Comment: @Roy: 1+ - thanks, how is that outside, i have content>>>DItems>>>within DItems i have Title - correct?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that Title, I assumed it was one on the outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
var xmlns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
xmlns.AddNamespace("DItems", "http://www.namespace.xsd");
xmldoc.Load(url);

var titleNodes = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//DItems:DItem/@Title", xmlns);

var result = titleNodes.Cast<XmlAttribute>().Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
```

Output (list of objects):

```
my title1
my title2
my title3
```

Comment: the reason why i am using in `for loop` is because i am adding my result into a dropdownlist as shown in my code...

Comment: @Abu, So what's the problem? Provide sample XML with multiple elements

Comment: okay so i try to looping something like this `foreach (XmlNode node in result)         
            {             
                string title = node.Attributes["Title"].Value;          
            } ` but i am getting error

Comment: cannot convert string to xmlnode

Comment: @Abu, `foreach (string title in result) { // title is of type string }`